# Axis labels run into axis when exporting plots with negative tick mark length (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

I'm having some trouble exporting a simple scatterplot to a pdf file in ggplot2. Specifically when I set the tick mark length to a negative value (essential), the tick mark labels merge with the axis line (as shown below).

[image: Problem tick mark labels]

The figure appears normally in the plot window of rstudio but when I export to pdf the problem occurs. Altering `vjust` in `axis.text.x` doesn't seem to be helping at all. I've also tried manipulating the plot margins.

Is anyone aware of a way of moving the labels away from the axis in such a situation?

Hopefully the code below should replicate the issue.

```
data = data.frame(xvar = seq(1:20), yvar = seq(1:20), labvar = rep(c("A", "B"), 10))

require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) +  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~labvar, scales = "fixed") +    
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"),
  axis.text.x=element_text(vjust = 0))

p
```

Comment: See Hadley's old comment on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/C0iGwoJy-Pw I suppose that's why `vjust` doesn't work. Is `unit(-0.05, "cm")` affordable? It fixed the overlapping for me.

Comment: @tonytonov Thanks for the link, interesting discussion. Reducing the length of the ticks does seem to be one way of doing the job, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `axis.ticks.margin`:

```
p + theme(axis.ticks.margin = unit(5, "lines"))
```

[image]

---

I notice that the documentation for `?theme` now includes a list of all theme elements and what they do.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Don't know how I missed it in the documentation but thank you.